# What will be the probability of getting Heads at 41th toss after first 40 toss were all tales?

Tags: probability

So, imagine, I have fixed probsbility of 0.6 for heads and 0.4 for tales

No matter how many times I toss, probsbility will reach that value 
So I tossed the coin 60 times and miraculously first 60 toss were all tales. This will intact intuitive increase the probability of heads becoming more often.

How do I formulate the probability of next coin toss being head?

Comment: It is "tails" ...and what value do you mean in "...will reach that value"? And with your info, the probability of tossing 60 consecutive tails is aprox $\;1.33\times 10^{-24}\;$ , a number so ridiculously low that it could practically be considered zero. Also, what does "...will intact intuitive increas" mean?

Comment: Suppose if I toss a coin 100 times and first 2 toss were tails, and intuitively I believe probability of heads coming out in next toss is more!! What is that specific probsbility

Comment: That probability is then whatever you want it to be as *your belief* in what the outcome can be affects decisively the probabilty of the actual outcome **for you** ...!

Comment: Okay!! I don’t know if you watch football or not, suppose Brazil won World Cup 3 times in a row!! So probability Brazil winning fourth World Cup is low!! Meaning probability of other country winning the cup after 3 wins is higher

Comment: I have found the answer myself!!

Comment: If a coin has 50:50 probsbility, out of 100 toss, there will be 49, 51 score differences, if I toss it infinite times it will be 50:50, but probsbility will always reach towards 50:50, as I approach infinity. So statistically speaking!! If I get 3 heads in a row, probsbility of tails is more this time, only for that next toss!!

Comment: Meaning probability of 3 tails and a Head is higher than Prbabiloty of 4 tails, so the answer IS, difference of two probsbility

Answer (score 0):

There is the mathematical model of a ${\bf p}=(0.6,0.4)$ coin. In this model, after you have observed $40$ tails in a row the probability for tail at the next throw is $0.4$.

Whether your concrete coin behaves according to the model I don't know.

Comment: No Sir, think about it, the answer has to be TTH- TTT

Comment: I mean, if you roll a dice, in order to reach the same probability, next toss will have Higher Probability

Comment: You see, sir, if Stock prices have 50:50 chances of High or Low, after 3 consecutive, market Crash, Stock prices will rise, because, to maintain 50:50 probsbility.

Comment: It’s like, if first 3 toss had, tails, in the fourth toss, probsbility of getting head is definitely above .5